# React + Redux :import from multiple files with the same statement?

Tags: reactjs, import, redux, react-redux

Would it be possible to `import *` from multiple files within the same import declaration i.e

Imports would usually be made with one file as follows

```
import * as action from '../actions/ActionCreators'
```

Would the following be possible by some means?

```
   import * as action from { '../firstActions/FirstActionCreators', '../secondActions/SecondActionCreators' }
```

whereby the same is import is made from two different directories/files.
Thanks

Comment: i don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to import only the required stuff. Since you are using ES6 you can try like this.

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory,IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
```